# How to create a MongoDB index with isodate?

Tags: mongodb

I've create and index for a query and its running is less then 1 second to retrieve millions of rows, but as soon as I add greater than ISODATE, it doesnt use indexes anymore.

the query is this one:

```
db.getCollection("Coll").find({"Field1.date" : {
                    $gte: ISODate("2019-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    $lte: ISODate("2019-11-28T00:00:00.000Z")                  
                }},{
    _id: 1,
    "Field2": 1,
    "Field3":1,
     Field4: 1
})
```

and i created an index like this:

```
//    db.Coll.createIndex(
//    {
//           _id: 1,
//    "Field2": 1,
//     Field4: 1,
//    "Field1.date":1
//    },
//    {background:true , name: "idx_name_date"})
//
```

but it seems this "field1.date" doesnt work with ISODate.

Comment: How does `Field1.date` look like?

Comment: Why an index on `_id`? This is the primary key and indexed by default.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the fields in the index definition is important.

The indexed values are sorted in the order the fields appear in the spec, so in the index: `{ _id: 1, Field2: 1,Field4: 1, "Field1.date":1}`, the values will be sorted first by _id, then by Field2, etc.

This means that in order to find documents with dates in the range you specified, it would have to examine *every* index entry.

It that case is probably just as efficient to scan all of the documents.

Instead build an index on `{ "Field1.date":1, _id: 1, Field2: 1,Field4: 1}`.  That will allow the query executor to find all of the documents by scanning a single subset of the index, and it will have all of the projected fields available to avoid fetching any documents.